# Xamarin: Anti-Aliasing doesnt work right {screenshot};

Tags: android, xamarin

so I am working on this app, that lets u pick a profile picture and then renders it into a circle to then show it back to the user. This is the result: [image: Screenshot]

So, the problem is the white border to the circle:
As u can see, it is not anti-aliased EVEN THOUGH we of course put anti-aliasing to "true".

Can u maybe help us out with this problem here? We cant find any better way to fix this, but it clearly shouldnt look like that...

Thanks a lot :)

Edit:

here is our code

```
public static Bitmap DrawBorder(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    float ratio = 0.97f;
    int width = bitmap.Width;
    int height = bitmap.Height;
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(width, height, Config.Argb8888);

    Path path = new Path();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(outputBitmap);

    //Draw Border
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.AntiAlias = true;
    paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
    paint.SetXfermode(null);
    //   paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
    paint.Color = Color.White;
    //   paint.StrokeWidth = 6;
    canvas.DrawCircle((float)width / 2, (float)height / 2, (float)Math.Min(width / 2, (height / 2)), paint);

    //Draw Picture 
    path.AddCircle(
              (float)(width / 2)
            , (float)(height / 2)
            , (float)Math.Min(width / 2, (height / 2)) * ratio
            , Path.Direction.Ccw);

    canvas.ClipPath(path);
    canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);



    return outputBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Is this on a device or on simulator? Also how are you creating the circular layout? I am missing some code to back this question up.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I edited the code in.